# Can not run TPL Dataflow pipeline

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to create a pipeline using `TPL Dataflow` where i can store messages in a batch block , and whenever its treshold is hit it would send the data to an action block.I have added a buffer block in case the action block is too slow.
So far i have tried all possible methods to move data from the first block to the second to no avail. I have linked the blocks , added the `DataFlowLinkOptions` of `PropagateCompletion` set to `true`. What else do I have to do in order for this pipeline to work ?

**Pipeline**

```
class LogPipeline<T>
{
    private ActionBlock<T[]> actionBlock;
    private BufferBlock<T> bufferBlock;
    private BatchBlock<T> batchBlock;
    private readonly Action<T[]> action;
    private readonly int BufferSize;
    private readonly int BatchSize;

    public LogPipeline(Action<T[]> action, int bufferSize = 4, int batchSize = 2)
    {
        this.BufferSize = bufferSize;
        this.BatchSize = batchSize;
        this.action = action;
    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<T>(new DataflowBlockOptions
            { TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default,
            BoundedCapacity = this.BufferSize });
        this.actionBlock = new ActionBlock<T[]>(this.action);
        this.batchBlock = new BatchBlock<T>(BatchSize);
        this.bufferBlock.LinkTo(this.batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
            { PropagateCompletion = true });
        this.batchBlock.LinkTo(this.actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
            { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }
    public void Post(T log)
    {
        this.bufferBlock.Post(log);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        actionBlock.Complete();
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestCase(100, 1000, 5)]
public void CanBatchPipelineResults(int batchSize, int bufferSize, int cycles)
{

    List<int> data = new List<int>();
    LogPipeline<int> logPipeline = new LogPipeline<int>(
       batchSize: batchSize,
       bufferSize: bufferSize,
       action: (logs) =>
       {
           data.AddRange(logs);
       });
    logPipeline.Start();

    int SelectWithEffect(int element)
    {
        logPipeline.Post(element);
        return 3;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (count++ > cycles)
        {
            break;
        }
        var sent = Parallel.For(0, bufferSize, (x) => SelectWithEffect(x));
    }
    logPipeline.Stop();
    Assert.IsTrue(data.Count == cycles * batchSize);
}
```

Why are all my blocks empty besides the buffer? I have tried with `SendAsync` also to no avail. No data is moved from the first block to the next no matter what I do.

I have both with and without the link options.

**Update** :
I have completely erased the pipeline and also the `Parallel`.
I have tried with all kinds of input blocks (batch/buffer/transform) and it seems there is no way subsequent blocks are getting something.
I have also tried with `await SendAsync` as well as `Post`.
I have only tried within `unit tests` classes.
Could this be the issue ?

**Update 2**
I was wrong complicating things , i have tried a more simple example . Inside a testcase even this doesnt work:

`List<int> items=new List<int>();
var tf=new TransformBlock<int,int>(x=>x+1);
var action= new ActionBlock<int>(x=>items.Add(x));
tf.LinkTo(action, new DataFlowOptions{ PropagateCompletion=true});
tf.Post(3);
//Breakpoint here`

Comment: May be something wrong with LinkTo options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline

Comment: You don't need a BufferBlock, both BatchBlock and ActionBlock have input buffers. Your code doesn't `await` the action block's completion either, so your application could terminate with unprocessed entries

Comment: `Parallel.For` btw is meant for parallel crunching of a *lot* of data using *all* processors, so it's completely inappropriate here unless you want to perform load testing with all cores occupied. The overall code isn't clear. What are you trying to do? Why not just write log entries directly to a `BufferBlock<int>` instead of all this?

Comment: `No data is moved from the first block to the next no matter what I do.` probably because your test terminates before the blocks had a chance to run. The loop and `Parallel.For` will keep *all* available cores occupied and `Assert.IsTrue` will run immediately, while most if not all messages are still in one of the buffers in the pipeline. You need to await for the last block's completion before checking the output.

Comment: I have tried without the parallel and there is no way i can get an item in the next block(s).

Comment: I want to be able to write messages to a `batch block` and whenever the batchblock threshold is hit i want to send the batch to an action block.The buffer block is just in case the action block takes too much to finish.

Comment: Because you never await for them to finish or even read the ActionBlock. You need to call `Complete()` on the *first* block and await the *last* block in the pipeline

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian you don't need the buffer blocks at all. All Dataflow blocks *already* have input buffers

Comment: I have a continous sequence there is no completion.I want it to run indefinitely.Are you saying in order to be able to see results in a downstream block i need to call `Conplete` on the upstream one ? In all examples i have looked there is no `await` ing nor `Complete` call.

Comment: Pipelines run indefinitely by default. `Complete()` is called only when you want the pipeline to terminate. Your test's problem is that it tries to count the output before the blocks even run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing seems to happen before the test ends is that none of the block has a chance to run. The code *blocks* all CPUs by using `Parallel.For` so no other task has a chance to run. This means that all posted messages are still in the first block. The code then calls `Complete` on the last block but doesn't even await for it to finish processing before checking the results.

The code can be simplified a lot. For starters, all blocks have input buffers, they don't need extra buffering.

The pipeline could be replaced with just this :

```
//Arrange
var list=new List<int>();

var head=new BatchBlock<int>(BatchSize);
var act=new ActionBlock<int[]>(nums=>list.AddRange(nums);

var options= new DataflowLinkOptions{ PropagateCompletion = true };
head.LinkTo(act);

//ACT

//Just fire everything at once, because why not
var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,cycles)(
    i=>Task.Run(()=> head.Post(i)));
await tasks;

//Tell the head block we're done
head.Complete();
//Wait for the last block to complete
await act.Completion;

//ASSERT
Assert.Equal(cycles, data.Count);
```

There's no real need to create a complex class to encapsulate the pipeline. It doesn't "start" - the blocks do nothing if they have no data. To abstract it, one only needs to provide access to the head block and the last block's `Completion` task

Comment: Excuse me if i am wrong but if i have a continous stream of data that i do not when it completes how can i issue `Complete` ? Do i have to reinstantiate the blocks for each time the pipeline completes some work?

Comment: Don't call `Complete()` if you don't want to stop the pipeline. `Complete()` doesn't make the block run, it tells a block it needs to stop and notify downstream blocks they also need to stop. This way you don't need to create a new pipeline

Comment: In your test though, you *do* have a finite sequence and you're actually trying to count the finite outputs. So you do need to call `Complete()` to ensure everything has finished running

Comment: That is what i am asking , in my use case i want whenever ` N` items are batched i want to perform an `IO` action and write them somewhere.So according to you i must never call `complete` in a real case scenario if i want the pipeline to loop indefinitely.

Comment: The pipeline doesn't loop at all. It processes messages as they are posted. It's no different than a shell script pipeline, where the pipeline stays up as long as you feed data  (files, streaming data, whatever) to the first program in the pipeline.

Comment: As for batching, that already works. When the BatchBlock receives N items it will emit an array of N items to the next block in the pipeline. This will keep running until you call `Complete()` or `Abort()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `logPipeline.Stop` immediately after sending the data to the `BufferBlock`, you are completing the `ActionBlock`, and so it declines all messages that the `BatchBlock` is trying  later to send to it. From the documentation of the [`ActionBlock.Complete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.complete) method:

> Signals to the dataflow block that it shouldn't accept or produce any more messages and shouldn't consume any more postponed messages.

---

**Update:** Regarding the updated requirements in the question:

> Whenever its threshold is hit it would send the data to an action block.

...my suggestion is to move this logic inside the `LogPipeline.Post` method. The method [`BufferBlock.Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) returns `false` if the block hasn't accepted the data sent to it.

```
public void Post(T log)
{
    if (!this.bufferBlock.Post(log)) this.actionBlock.Post(log);
}
```

Comment: I have tried without the stop.I have even tried a buffer linked to a transform and vice versa and nothing is passed